# How to create multiple Docker Swarm Service using same image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am new to Docker Swarm I need to create different Docker Swarm Stack which is accessible via different url for different environment like dev, qa using same image.

```
Ex - service1 - http://service1
     service2 - http://service2
```

**docker-compose-dev.yaml**

```
services:
  service1:
    image: image
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        com.docker.lb.hosts: demo-dev.example.com
        com.docker.lb.port: 8181
        com.docker.lb.network: demo_service1-network
        com.docker.ucp.access.label: '/development'
    networks:
      - service1-network

networks:
  service1-network:
    driver: overlay
```

**docker-compose-qa.yaml**

```
services:
  service2:
    image: image
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        com.docker.lb.hosts: demo-qa.example.com
        com.docker.lb.port: 8181
        com.docker.lb.network: demo_service2-network
        com.docker.ucp.access.label: '/development'
    networks:
      - service2-network

networks:
  service2-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: getting bad gateway error, does this com.docker.lb.network network really matter.

Comment: If a single network is declared, than this parameter is option (unless you specify com.docker.lb.ssl_passthrough). Just to be clear: you do run Docker Enterprise, installed UCP and enabled Interlock? Also the value for the label com.docker.lb.network is composed of {stackname}_{networkname} (unless it's an externaly created network).